# Is it possible to specify sub-sub classes within a <style>?

Tags: html, css, class

Example:

```
<style> div.Style1 div img { border: 3px red solid } </style>
...
<div class="Style1" id="divMain">
    <img src="http://someurl.com/someimg.jpg" /> <!--WON'T be styled-->
    <div id="divSub">
        <img src="http://someurl.com/someimg.jpg" /> <!--WILL be styled-->
    </div> <!--End of divSub-->
</div> <!--End of divMain-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it selects only images that are children of a div that are themselves children of the element with class `Style1`.

```
.Style1 > div > img {
  border: 3px red solid 
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I like this type of syntax. Are there any side effects that come with using the '>'?

Comment: It selects only direct children and it also renders faster.

Comment: @Pekka: Fair enough, although that may not be the highest priority anymore. Certainly not for the specific project I am working on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This CSS:

```
div.Style1 div img { 
  border: 3px red solid;
}
```

says: apply `border: 3px red solid;` to all `img` elements within a `div` element, which are in turn in in another `div` that has `Style1` as a class.

Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WZ3rk/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - try it out. Although I would use

```
div.Style1 div.divSub img  { ... }
```

Comment: Would that require the secondary div to have class="divSub"?